# Can I save these hosta leaves by putting them in a glass of water?

Tags: hosta

As previously posted I am having issues with my hostsas
One of them looks like this
[image]

I cam across this article that says the leaves could be saved if cut and set in a glass of water like in this article. Is this true? Can I propagate hostas this way?
https://www.hometalk.com/3899783/you-can-save-that-hosta

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your hosta is in too much sun and/or is not being watered enough. It seems to be one of the blue-leaved hostas, and these hostas are not known to be particularly sun tolerant (the gold-leaves ones can take much more sun than the blue-leaved cultivars).

If your hosta is indeed in the shade (about 4 hours or less of sun), then I wouldn't worry about it - just make sure it's getting enough water. If it's NOT in the shade, then the easiest way to save it is to transplant it to a location that IS in the shade.

Your link shows someone saving leaves that have a bit of the crown attached, which looks doable, but then again, the author of that page confuses moles with voles, so...

Comment: I am considering adding a screen there. It has shade in the morning but then the it takes a lot of sun in the afternoon